# Python: is there a TrueType font library?

Tags: python, truetype

I need to extract information from .ttf files. Such as the font's name and style. Maybe some more info in future. How to do this in Python more easily than looking for a specification and coding a lot?

A short code example would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this out: [How to extract font names from TTF files using Python and our old friend 'the command line'](http://www.starrhorne.com/2012/01/18/how-to-extract-font-names-from-ttf-files-using-python-and-our-old-friend-the-command-line.html)

Note: This took me about 10 seconds to google...

Comment: I always will search before asking questions. I always will search before asking questions. I always will search before asking questions.